# simpleCart JS view cart is displaying all item info in one column. How to style output?

Tags: javascript, simplecart

My simpleCart js view cart is outputting all of the item info into a single column instead of formatting it into a table. How do you style the output of the view cart?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the output to a table using 'cartStyle : "table"' in your initialization:

```
simpleCart({
    checkout : {
        type : "SendForm",
        url : "cart.php",

        ... etc

    },
    cartStyle : "table"
});
```

Docs: http://simplecartjs.org/documentation/setup_initialization